# Pushing the AL register in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, nasm, instruction-set

I am making my own OS in 16 bits x86 assembly with NASM and in one part of the code I have to `push` the AL register to the stack. But when I do `push al` I just says:

> firstos.asm:127: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands

I also tried using the stack pointer with `mov sp, al` but that didn't work.

How can I do this?

Comment: `mov sp, <register>` is **not** an alternative to `push`. A `mov` from a 16-bit GPR to `sp` is possible, but it does something very different than `push`.

Comment: @ecm: I suspect they were thinking of `mov [sp], al` but of course that is not encodable on x86-16.  And even if it were, it would overwrite the last byte pushed on the stack, without adjusting the stack pointer, which is probably not desired.

Answer (score 4):

There is no instruction to push an 8-bit register.  The instruction set is designed with the assumption that you will organize the stack in terms of 16-bit words, so all pushes and pops should be word sized.

So most likely you just want to `push ax`, and then `pop ax` later.

If in the meantime you want to put something in `ah` that you *don't* want to overwrite, it gets a little more difficult.  Preferably, use some other register for that byte instead.

Comment: What other registers can I use for that?

Comment: @phasmida: Any register that you aren't already using for something else.  I can't be more specific without seeing your entire code.

Comment: @phasmida Other than AL and AH, the other byte-sized registers that you can use are BL, BH, CL, CH, DL, and DH. And never forget that two by two these byte-sized registers are part of a single word-sized register: BL and BH together are BX, CL and CH together are CX, ...